# Pasar una cadena a un objeto

Tags: java

Necesito de su ayuda, tengo una cadena como el siguiente

```
String texto= "[{abc-123,mazda,caba,2016,s,26000};
{xyz-215,nissan,almera,2014,a,18000};{efg-901,mazda,2,2012,m,17000}]";
```

Necesito que esta cadena se separe y agregar todos a un `ArrayList` de un objeto Automóvil que tiene los siguientes campos de `placa`, `marca`, `modelo`, `anio`, `transmisión` y `precio` respectivamente.

He utilizado el método `substring` dentro de un `for` para separarlo, luego he reemplazado los caracteres no deseados y lo he guardado en otra cadena lo cual me da como resultado  lo siguiente.

```
  abc-123,mazda,caba,2016,s,26000
  xyz-215,nissan,almera,2014,a,18000
  efg-901,mazda,2,2012,m,17000
```

Aun así no puedo agregar este `string`, donde lo guardo, a mi lista de objetos automóvil.

```
List<Automovil> lista = new ArrayList<Automovil>();
```

PSDT: Soy nuevo en el foro, espero que me haya dejado entender, aprecio mucho su tiempo dedicado a ayudarme.

Comment: Falta información: qué pasa si uno de los strings originales (por ejemplo, un modelo de auto) contiene uno de los caracteres especiales: `{}[],;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pueden haber muchas formas de hacer esta tarea , para este caso plantearé una opción. En primer lugar hay que reemplazar los caracteres especiales **`Excepto`** los que nos permitirán separar los registros y los atributos que son el **`;`** y la **`,`**

```
String texto= "[{abc-123,mazda,caba,2016,s,26000};
               {xyz-215,nissan,almera,2014,a,18000};{efg-901,mazda,2,2012,m,17000}]";
/* Reemplazamos los { , [] y } */
texto = texto.replaceAll("[{\\[\\]}]", "");
```

Luego de reemplazar procedemos a separar los registros haciendo uso de `split` , en la variable partes tendremos los valores que se pasarán al constructor de su clase automóvil.

```
for (String partes : texto.split(";")) {
  String[] part  = partes.split(",") ;
  /* Hacemos uso del Constructor , si los tipos de datos sin diferentes 
    solo es cuestión de parsear al tipo correspondiente */
  Automovil movil = new Automovil( part[0], part[1], part[2], Integer.parseInt(part[3]), 
                                    part[4], Float.parseFloat(part[5]));
  /* Añadimos a la Lista el Objeto*/
  lista.add(movil);
}
```

Para que esto funcione en su clase `Automovil` debería tener un constructor parecido a esto , si no es así debería adaptarlo y hacer el `cast` respectivo al momento de llamar al constructor.

```
 public Automovil(String placa, String marca, String modelo, int anio, String transmision, float precio) {
    this.placa = placa;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.anio = anio;
    this.transmision = transmision;
    this.precio = precio;
}
```

Comment: Gracias.. me salvastes de una amanecida

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
String cadena = "abc-123,mazda,caba,2016,s,26000;"
                    +"xyz-215,nissan,almera,2014,a,18000;"
                    + "efg-901,mazda,2,2012,m,17000;";
    ArrayList<Automovil> lista = new ArrayList<Automovil>();

    String split[] = cadena.split(";");
    for (int x = 0; x < split.length; x++) {
        String splitFila[] = split[x].split(",");
        lista.add(new Automovil(splitFila[0],splitFila[1],splitFila[2],splitFila[3],splitFila[4],splitFila[5]));
    }
```

separa cada fila por algun caracter, en este caso por el punto y coma ( ; ).

luego has un split de la cadena , separala las filas por el punto y coma y luego has un split de la fila cuando encuentre una coma ( , ), esto para separar cada elemento, en este caso el split de la fila sera de tamaño 6.

Ahora solo crea un objeto automovil y guardalo al ArrayList.